# No of ways to reach a cell in a grid

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search

We are given a grid of `N*N`, we are to start at a `source` position and end at a `destination`. We have to find the number of ways to do it. Will an answer to this problem be possible if all four direction movements (`up`, `left`, `down`, `right`) are allowed?

I know the answer if only `right` and `down` traversals are allowed. In that case we do `bfs` and store the answer in a table for each cell.

Also what happens in the first case, if some cells are blocked? Can we arrive at the answer now?

Comment: "Also what happens in the first case, if some cells are blocked?". Answer at this cell will be 0, because the cell is unreachable, but algorithm for non-blocked cells stays the came.

Comment: I assume nodes of the grid can only be visited once for one route, correct?

Comment: @SaiBot No such restriction was given in the question. But in my view if we have to get an answer other than infinity, then we have to assume that.

Comment: I feel we have to somehow save the cells that we traverse along the way to destination cell and once we reach destination cell, we save it in a set in order to get unique count of paths to our destination.

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  Is it possible efficiently?  Probably not.  See https://knowledge.e.southern.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1092&context=senior_research for a variant of just counting non-selfintersecting paths starting at a point with no target stopping point.  It is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: Why can't you run bfs with 4 directions ? Also if you want to map all possible paths use dfs.